# Why getting the length of a list gives an error?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, abstract

I have an abstract class called Product and two classes (RestaurantProducts , ClothesProducts) extending from the abstract class.
I want to create a grid of RestaurantProducts and a grid of clothesProducts.
I created a List of RestaurantProducts and a list of ClothesProducst, but every time I try to get the length of these lists, I get an error saying : type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

```
class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsGrid({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 300,
        childAspectRatio: 2 / 2.5,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
      itemCount: DummyData.clothesProducts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ProductItem(
          id: DummyData.clothesProducts[index].id,
          imageUrl: DummyData.clothesProducts[index].imageUrl[0],
          title: DummyData.clothesProducts[index].title,
          likes: DummyData.clothesProducts[index].likes,
          dislikes: DummyData.clothesProducts[index].dislikes,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


 class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final List<String> imageUrl;
  final int likes;
  final int dislikes;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final List<String> categories;
  final List<String> types;
  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.likes,
    required this.dislikes,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.categories,
    required this.types,
  });
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_five/models/product.dart';

class ColthesProduct extends Product {
  final List<Color> colors;
  final List<String> sizes;
  final List<String> materials;

  ColthesProduct(
      {required id,
      required title,
      required description,
      required price,
      required imageUrl,
      required likes,
      required dislikes,
      required createdAt,
      required categories,
      required types,
      required this.colors,
      required this.sizes,
      required this.materials})
      : super(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            categories: categories,
            createdAt: createdAt,
            description: description,
            dislikes: dislikes,
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            likes: likes,
            price: price,
            types: types);
}


static List<ColthesProduct> clothesProducts = [
    ColthesProduct(...),
    ColthesProduct(...),
]
```

I realized that the problem is coming from itemCount in the GridView.builder when it tries to get the length of the list.

Note: Before I created the abstract class and extended each of the two classes from the abstract one, it was working with no errors.

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the length of the list; the length will always be an int. 

Check if all the prices are integers, probably some prices are passed as double :D

Comment: I tried to replace the ProductItem that is returned from itemBuilder with a container and the problem still exists. Also, I replaced the value of itemCount with a static value like 10 and it worked with no errors. So, the problem is DummyData.clothesProducts.length :(

Comment: Can you share the output of print(DummyData.clothesProducts)

Comment: It gives the same error type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Comment: Somewhere you are passing an `int` where a `double` is expected, so you must call `.toDouble()` wherever that's occurring.  I am highly skeptical that the problem is with the `DummyData.clothesProduct.length` line since `.length` should be an `int`, and `GridView.builder`'s `itemCount` parameter is also an `int`.  If you still can't solve your problem, I highly suggest eliminating code to create a minimal example that is complete enough to allow other people to reproduce your problem.